# Нужно ли импортировать путь класса, если он в одной папке?

Tags: java, объекты

[image: Первое изображение]

[image: Второе изображение]

Если не делать импорт на создаваемой мной класс это правильно ?

Comment: Ну если вы можете их использовать, то, наверное, не нужно? У вас всё светится красным? У вас вылетают ошибки? Нет! Более того, нельзя импортировать классы, лежащие в одном пакете с данным.

Comment: На скринах прога работает нормально, но вопрос все-таки возник... может не так сформулирован?

Comment: @ИмяФамилия Не могли бы вы, пожалуйста, быть более терпимы к людям, задающим здесь вопросы? Ваши мысли, как я считаю, можно было бы выражать более спокойно.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Нет, не нужно. (ваш кэп, ну видно же)